# WW1 trying to identify squadron and aircrew

Tags: world-war-one, identification, britain

Recently discovered photo belonging to my grandfather. I was told he took this but not so sure...
He was connected with 57 Squadron but I can find no info about it.
Keen to be able to identify anyone in this photo but no idea where to start. The plane is a DH4, I believe.[image]

Comment: Wikipedia's page on [No. 57 Squadron RAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._57_Squadron_RAF) is a good place to start, and has links to more detailed sources.